# Draw a white line in opengl es

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I have an image.  Over it I draw a semi transparent polygon.  Over the semi transparent polygon I draw a line.

I cannot seem to get this line to be white.  It is almost as though it is blending with the image or polygon.

```
    glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, area.polygonShapeData.totalPoints);
```

What could I be doing to make this line not be white?  It comes out a darker gray.

Comment: I did not disable Texture2d i had mistyped and was calling a different function.  Thanks for helping me figure out that I had to disable something.

Comment: Hello ! Could you explain me how you draw a polygon with OpenGL ES ? I'm near to kill me (I begin with OpenGL ES) ^^ I searched and googled so much without succeeding, Thanks !

Comment: Hello Mel. I need your help to draw a line using OpenGL ES framework. I trying to draw a straight line from top - bottom without rotation animation. Can you please suggest any sample code to draw a line? I have posted a question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736887/draw-a-straight-line-using-opengl-es-in-iphone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you use anti-aliasing? I've noticed hair thin lines coming out faded if **GL_LINE_SMOOTH** is enabled. Also try increasing the width with [glLineWidth](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glLineWidth.xml).

Comment: Both good points--antialiasing messes with intensity values to try to put the right amount of intensity on the idealized (vs. scan converted) line.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you've got blending enabled in something like GL_DST_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_ALPHA mode?  Try **glDisable(GL_BLEND)** and see if you get better results.

Comment: I put glDisable(GL_Blend right before the glcolors line but it is still coming out gray